# MacOS: Cannot find .ivy2 folder on macOS

Tags: macos, hadoop, dependency-injection

I'm running a spark job locally. The system requires two following dependencies:

`hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar`
`aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`

to be stored in path: /Users/sonmt/.ivy2/jars (*sonmt* is my username).

However I can not find that location using Finder on MacOS (BigSur 11.2.3). So any recommendations on how to find that folder, or any other way to import these 2 dependencies (without using mvn).

Thanks so much for your help. Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it seems like I cannot get access to the directory Users/sonmt/.ivy2, but there is another way to import dependencies into spark-submit command with parameter `--packages`

In this case, I used:

`spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-javasdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 /path/to/spark/job`

And the problem is solved!